# Gradle task to do Grals 3 schema-export

Tags: grails, gradle, schemaexport

In Grails 2 I had a gradle task that would do a schema-export.

`task extractGrailsDDL(type: org.grails.gradle.plugin.tasks.GrailsTask) {
    command "schema-export"
    args  ddlFileName("Temp") + " --datasouce=operator"
}`

org.grails.gradle.plugin.tasks.GrailsTask doesn't exist in the grails.gradle.plugin for Grails 3.

How can I write a Gradle task to run a schema-export and pass parameters?

Comment: I suggest you look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432203/can-grails-2-x-schema-export-or-similar-command-generate-ddl-for-schema-update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grails 3 schema-export in build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44557319/grails-3-schema-export-in-build-gradle)