# Grails 3 schema-export in build.gradle

Tags: grails, gradle, schemaexport

In Grails 2 I had a nifty gradle task that would generate DDL for me:

```
task extractGrailsDDL(type: org.grails.gradle.plugin.tasks.GrailsTask) {
    command "schema-export"
    args  ddlFileName("Temp") + " --datasouce=operator"
```

}

But that doesn't work in Grails 3, I get that, a lot has changed.

The question is: How can I create a Gradle Task to run a schema export and pass file name and datasource parameters to it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a Gradle task. A task already exists.

http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/schema-export.html

Comment: Thanks James.I have seen that documentation. My question was about how I can run schema-export in a Gradle Task and pass parameters? There are other tasks that depend on the schema-export and methods which work out the parameter values.

Comment: What parameters do you want to pass?